# Using Ransack to generate custom Active Admin Filter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I am looking to create a custom filter that will search other tables data based on the associations I have set up, I have achieved this within my view but cannot transfer this to a custom filter with Ransack.

I am trying search on `Tournament name`.

I have the following 3 models and associations setup:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  has_many :gallery_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_images, allow_destroy: :true
end

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fixtures, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :gallery, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :gallery_images, through: :gallery, dependent: :destroy
end

class GalleryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

In my view as stated I have achieved this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register GalleryImage do
  index do
    selectable_column
    column 'Tournament' do |gal|
      tourn = gal.gallery
      tourn.tournament.name
    end
  end
end
```

How would I make this into a query using Ransack?

```
filter :custom_ransacker_method
       as: :select,
       collection: -> { Tournament.pluck(:name, :id) },
       label: 'Tournament Name'
```

I am not sure on how to construct the custom ransacker method.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations

Comment: thanks @TimoSchilling I was looking at that and can see if i was doing this in a controller method then i could probably make some headway, but getting it to work in a custom  filter? thats where i am struggling